# Drawing a convex/concave quadrilateral in Java

Tags: java, jframe, polygon

I have four randomly sorted points, and I can't seem to draw a convex/concave `Polygon` with these points. This is the code I am using:

```
int xPoly[] = new int[4];
int yPoly[] = new int[4];

for(int i = 0; i < quad.size(); i++){
  g2d.fill(quad.get(i));
  xPoly[i] = (int) (quad.get(i).getX());
  yPoly[i] = (int) (quad.get(i).getY());
}

Polygon poly = new Poylgon(xPoly, yPoly, xPoly.length);
g2d.draw(poly);
```

Where `quad` is defined as `ArrayList<Point> quad = new ArrayList();`. Point is a simple class I wrote which is self explanatory. However, my solution keeps producing polygons like this:

[image]

The black points are part of `quad`. My desired result is a normal looking polygon, not an irregular one.

An example for the `quad` ArrayList:

```
(0,0), (5,3) (9,10), (6, 7)
```

There is no specified order for these points, so `xPoly and yPoly` aren't necessarily ordered either.

Comment: Are you adding the points in the right order? Can you show some examples of the values you're adding (Consider a SSCCE).

Comment: @Kylar I have not specified an order. In what order should I be adding them?

Comment: @Kylar I gave an example of four random points. Also the polygon can be concave or convex. It Just can't be like the image shown (no intersections).

Comment: A Polygon object will draw in the order of the points that you add them, that's why you're getting the crosssed lines. The picture you have does not match the points that you posted.

Comment: A Polygon is just a holder for a set of points - the order is very important when it comes to drawing.

Comment: @Kylar I fixed it by swapping xPoly[0] with xPoly[1] and yPoly[0] with yPoly[1]. Thanks for your help, for some reason I thought it would order the points automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Switched to an answer:

You must order the points in a Polygon yourself - the points in a Polygon describe a fixed order in which it will be drawn. It won't interpolate what type of shape you want.